# How do I translate Decode(Packet) function in C++?

Tags: python, c++, packet, np

I am learning depth ai and I found this example on their repo. https://github.com/luxonis/depthai-experiments/tree/master/gen2-road-segmentation. I started translating this code in C++ to be consistent with the project I am putting together. I run into this function named "Decode"

```
def decode(packet):
    data = np.squeeze(toTensorResult(packet)["L0317_ReWeight_SoftMax"])
    class_colors = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255]]
    class_colors = np.asarray(class_colors, dtype=np.uint8)
    indices = np.argmax(data, axis=0)
    output_colors = np.take(class_colors, indices, axis=0)
    return output_colors
```

Adding more detail regarding the problem.
DepthAI offers a lot of examples in their core repo
https://github.com/luxonis/depthai-core

I used some of those example to start shaping the segmentation script since its a feature that I don't find written in C++ between all of the examples.

Here is my progress so far.

```
#include <chrono>
#include "depthai-core/examples/utility/utility.hpp"
#include <depthai/depthai.hpp>
#include "slar.hpp"

using namespace slar;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

static std::atomic<bool> syncNN{true};

void slar_depth_segmentation::segment(int argc, char **argv, dai::Pipeline &pipeline,
                                      cv::Mat frame,
                                      dai::Device *device_unused) {
    // blob model
    std::string nnPath("/Users/alessiograncini/road-segmentation-adas-0001.blob");
    if (argc > 1) {
        nnPath = std::string(argv[1]);
    }
    printf("Using blob at path: %s\n", nnPath.c_str());

    // in
    auto camRgb = pipeline.create<dai::node::ColorCamera>();
    auto imageManip = pipeline.create<dai::node::ImageManip>();
    auto mobilenetDet = pipeline.create<dai::node::MobileNetDetectionNetwork>();
    // out
    auto xoutRgb = pipeline.create<dai::node::XLinkOut>();
    auto nnOut = pipeline.create<dai::node::XLinkOut>();
    auto xoutManip = pipeline.create<dai::node::XLinkOut>();
    // stream names
    xoutRgb->setStreamName("camera");
    xoutManip->setStreamName("manip");
    nnOut->setStreamName("segmentation");
    //
    imageManip->initialConfig.setResize(300, 300);
    imageManip->initialConfig.setFrameType(dai::ImgFrame::Type::BGR888p);

    // properties
    camRgb->setPreviewSize(300, 300);
    camRgb->setBoardSocket(dai::CameraBoardSocket::RGB);
    camRgb->setResolution(dai::ColorCameraProperties::SensorResolution::THE_1080_P);
    camRgb->setInterleaved(false);
    camRgb->setColorOrder(dai::ColorCameraProperties::ColorOrder::RGB);
    //
    mobilenetDet->setConfidenceThreshold(0.5f);
    mobilenetDet->setBlobPath(nnPath);
    mobilenetDet->setNumInferenceThreads(2);
    mobilenetDet->input.setBlocking(false);
    // link
    camRgb->preview.link(xoutRgb->input);
    imageManip->out.link(mobilenetDet->input);
    //
    if (syncNN) {
        mobilenetDet->passthrough.link(xoutManip->input);
    } else {
        imageManip->out.link(xoutManip->input);
    }
    //
    mobilenetDet->out.link(nnOut->input);
    // device
    dai::Device device(pipeline);

    // queues
    auto previewQueue = device.getOutputQueue("camera", 4, false);
    auto detectionNNQueue = device.getOutputQueue("segmentation", 4, false);

    // fps
    auto startTime = steady_clock::now();
    int counter = 0;
    float fps = 0;
    auto color = cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255);

    // main
    while (true) {
        auto inRgb = previewQueue->get<dai::ImgFrame>();
        auto inSeg = detectionNNQueue->get<dai::NNData>();
        //?
        auto segmentations = inSeg->getData();
        //
        counter++;
        auto currentTime = steady_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = duration_cast<duration<float>>(currentTime - startTime);
        if(elapsed > seconds(1)) {
            fps = counter / elapsed.count();
            counter = 0;
            startTime = currentTime;
        }

        // testing if mat is a good replacement for
        // the input array as in "decode" the inSeg data is manipulated
        // cv::Mat img(500, 1000, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(70));
        // slar_depth_segmentation::draw(segmentations, frame);
        std::stringstream fpsStr;
        fpsStr << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << fps;

        cv::imshow("camera window", inRgb->getCvFrame());
        //cv::imshow("camera window", frame);


        int key = cv::waitKey(1);
        if (key == 'q' || key == 'Q') {
            break;
        }
    }
}


void slar_depth_segmentation::draw(cv::InputArray data, cv::OutputArray frame) {
    cv::addWeighted(frame, 1, data, 0.2, 0, frame);
}
//https://jclay.github.io/dev-journal/simple_cpp_argmax_argmin.html
void slar_depth_segmentation::decode( cv::InputArray data) {
    vector <int> class_colors [4] =
            {{0,0,0},{0,255,0},{255, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 255}};
  
}
```

I can successfully play the camera using this script - but as you can tell the only part of the segmentation that is translated is the draw method, that is a function equivalent for both py and c++ since it's part of the openCV library.
I am getting stuck in trying to write the equivalent of the decode method. Thanks

[edit]

Any suggestion regarding this follow up??

C++

```
cv::InputArray slar_depth_segmentation::decode(std::vector<std::uint8_t> data) {

    // reshape or np.squeeze
    data.resize(1, 1);
    // create a vector array
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> classColors{
            {0,   0,   0},
            {0,   255, 0},
            {255, 0,   0},
            {0,   0,   255}};

    double minVal;
    double maxVal;
    cv::minMaxIdx(
            data,
            &minVal,
            &maxVal);
    // get max value of class colors
    auto output_colors = classColors[&maxVal, 0];
    return output_colors;
}
```

Py

```
def decode(packet):
    data = np.squeeze(toTensorResult(packet)["L0317_ReWeight_SoftMax"])
    class_colors = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255]]
    class_colors = np.asarray(class_colors, dtype=np.uint8)
    indices = np.argmax(data, axis=0)
    output_colors = np.take(class_colors, indices, axis=0)
    return output_colors
```

Comment: Code translation questions are considered [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-language-to-this-language-too-broad). Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. Describe the problem you are trying to solve in the language you are trying to use. Provide a [mre] with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show your attempt and describe exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Additionaly, code translation does not get implemented by translating one line of code to another one, verbatim. This approach to code translation always ends in tears. The correct way to do so is to analyze the ***entire*** program, logically, identifying discrete logical units that can be converted to their identical functional equivalent in the other language, then ***reimplementing*** each logical unit, from scratch, in the other programming language. Especially since Python is so fundamentally different from C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
#I think you are looking for the 
cv::argmax # function.

cv::argmax # returns the index of the maximum value in an array.
cv::argmax # is available in OpenCV 3.4.3 and later.
```

Comment: thanks for answering, since cv::argmax # returns the index of the maximum value in an array would this make sense? I edited my initial question